# JSON containing array object - ajax call results empty

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the following JSON source
[image]

Two of my name/value pairs `kpiRecordedMissesNoPlannerMatch` and `goodShipmentPlannerSaidMissed`contain object arrays.

When I make the ajax call the arrays come through empty. 
[image]

Here is the code I'm using to make the ajax call.

```
var urlString = '../api/APILPlus/APILPlusMissingComments/PS/DMPSPM/2018-11-01/2018-11-30';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: urlString,
    success: function (json) {

        console.log('json'); console.log(json);

    }
});
```

When I hard code the same JSON output from the browser the array fills as expected.

```
var manualJson = [{ "dels": 116, "kpiRecordedMissesNoPlannerMatch": [{ "delivery": "1188724924", "material": "0281006949562", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188771856", "material": "0281006949562", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188644995", "material": "0281006950562", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188740584", "material": "02810075106RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188740588", "material": "02810075106RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188711251", "material": "02810079346RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188772925", "material": "02810079346RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188644995", "material": "0281006954562", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188786351", "material": "02810072632G9", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 50.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188740585", "material": "02810069446RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188740582", "material": "02810075146RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188770521", "material": "02810078782G9", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188805487", "material": "02810065116RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 50.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188740583", "material": "02810075126RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188711238", "material": "02810079366RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }, { "delivery": "1188772925", "material": "02810079366RY", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 0.00, "cause": "No Planner answer." }], "goodShipmentPlannerSaidMissed": [{ "delivery": "1188691604", "material": "02810072632G9", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 100.00, "cause": "Supplier Backlog/ Late", "m11": 100.00 }, { "delivery": "1188659715", "material": "02810074965UR", "materialDesc": "Particulate matter p", "sum": 100.00, "cause": "Supplier Backlog/ Late", "m11": 100.00 }] }];
console.log('manualJson'); console.log(manualJson);
```

[image]

I don't understand what I'm missing.  Help is appreciated as always!

UPDATE: 
Additional information.  Network console from browser.
[image]

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console. Does the response for your AJAX request have data in the arrays?

Comment: FYI: GET requests do not typically have a `Content-type` as they have no request body

Comment: @Phil I have added a picture of the network console to my post. This type of json containing array objects is new to me.  It strikes me as strange the `dels` received a quantity from the call but the object arrays are blank.  In the past, I have no problems when the json contains no objects.

Comment: The url in your browser screenshot differs from the one in your network tab. Can you confirm the results in the network tab if you use the browser url in your javascript code?

Comment: The network tab clearly shows that the arrays are empty.

Comment: I updated the network picture.  Hovering over shows the same URL as in the first picture.

Comment: No it doesn't. The URL in your first screenshot is `2018-11-01/2018-11-30` but the hover URL is `2018-11-01/2018-11-01`

Comment: I realized this about the same time you posted this also.  Stupid mistake really.  But I really appreciate your help that night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!  The URL date range in my javascript was not fully correct.  I've corrected the calculation to include the full month date range (which definitely has data).

Here's the network console.
[image]

And the final JSON as expected. 
[image]

Thank you to everyone who helped work through it with me this evening.  Your comments are most appreciated!